# setting multiple variables in if statement using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I have a batch script where I need to set multiple variables when a user enters a number. For some reason the country isn't getting set. What am I doing wrong?

```
set /P CLIENTOPTION=CLIENT:
IF /I '%CLIENTOPTION%'=='1' set CLIENTCHOICE=y set COUNTRY=UK
IF /I '%CLIENTOPTION%'=='2' set CLIENTCHOICE=w set COUNTRY=UK
IF /I '%CLIENTOPTION%'=='3' set CLIENTCHOICE=x set COUNTRY=UK
IF /I '%CLIENTOPTION%'=='4' set CLIENTCHOICE=y set COUNTRY=USA
IF /I '%CLIENTOPTION%'=='5' set CLIENTCHOICE=z set COUNTRY=CANADA
```

Answer (score 8):

This could be made more robust but all you are missing is the `&` command separator.

```
set /P CLIENTOPTION=CLIENT:
IF /I '%CLIENTOPTION%'=='1' set CLIENTCHOICE=y&set COUNTRY=UK
IF /I '%CLIENTOPTION%'=='2' set CLIENTCHOICE=w&set COUNTRY=UK
IF /I '%CLIENTOPTION%'=='3' set CLIENTCHOICE=x&set COUNTRY=UK
IF /I '%CLIENTOPTION%'=='4' set CLIENTCHOICE=y&set COUNTRY=USA
IF /I '%CLIENTOPTION%'=='5' set CLIENTCHOICE=z&set COUNTRY=CANADA
```

Answer (score 3):

The assignment uses everything on the same line after `=`.  For example, for `CLIENTOPTIONS === 1`, the variable `CLIENTCHOICE` is being assigned everything after `=`, which is the string `"y set COUNTRY=UK"`.  Obviously, not what you intended.

You can get around this, and get the expected behavior, by using parentheses, and placing each action on a separate line, like so:

```
set /P CLIENTOPTION=CLIENT:
IF /I '%CLIENTOPTION%'=='1' ( 
    set CLIENTCHOICE=y
    set COUNTRY=UK
)
IF /I '%CLIENTOPTION%'=='2' ( 
    set CLIENTCHOICE=w 
    set COUNTRY=UK
)
IF /I '%CLIENTOPTION%'=='3' ( 
    set CLIENTCHOICE=x 
    set COUNTRY=UK
)
IF /I '%CLIENTOPTION%'=='4' ( 
    set CLIENTCHOICE=y 
    set COUNTRY=USA
)
IF /I '%CLIENTOPTION%'=='5' (
    set CLIENTCHOICE=z 
    set COUNTRY=CANADA
)
```